# Beginner stuck on the task of making a working html and css quiz

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn the beginnings of html and css and as my first task I was asked to make a function quiz with html and css coding.

I cannot get help from the people who tasked me with this as I cannot get ahold of them and I am hoping that others may be able to give me some pointers and advice of what I need to do to get the functions right.

I have only done half a day of learning on this and only have 1 powerpoint on how to do my task but it doesn't cover everything that needs to be done or how to use the coding suggested to get the outcome I want to get.

Here is my html coding for one of my questions:

```
<h2>Question1</h2>
        <h3>Which type of dog would you expect to find on a farm?</h3>
        <p id="OptionOne"><img src="https://www.mybestfrienddogcare.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/border-collie-.png"width="150"height="150"><input type="checkbox"></p>
        <p id="OptionTwo"><img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg"width="150"height="150"><input type="checkbox"></p>
        <p id="OptionThree"><img src="https://www.pdsa.org.uk/media/6615/german-shepherd-gallery-1-min.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&quality=100&height=500&bgcolor=fff&rnd=132019595560000000"width="150"height="150"><input type="checkbox"></p>
        <p id="OptionFour"><img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2016/09/beagle-puppy-5-e1568913038666.jpg"width="150"height="150"><input type="checkbox"></p>
```

I only want it possible for 1 answer to be optional out of each of these answers, I have 5 questions in total to do and couldn't get the radio button function to work for the whole quiz, hence the checkboxes instead.

I am suppose to be able to select an answer for all 5 questions then click on a link to view answers to then display all the correct answers on the next page as well as displaying how many questions were answered correctly.

I have never used either coding before this point so any help and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Laufeena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your HTML rewritten with JavaScript and CSS to include the basic required functionality, assuming that the answer to the first question is dog one.

Now you need to try and replicate this for the entire quiz.

```js
const $form = document.getElementById('form')
const $dogOne = document.getElementById('dog-one')
const $results = document.getElementById('results')

$form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()

  if ($dogOne.checked) {
    $results.innerHTML = '<p class="success">Correct!</p>'
  } else {
    $results.innerHTML = '<p class="fail">Nope. The correct answer was dog 1</p>'
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.success {
  color: seagreen;
}

.fail {
  color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<h2>Question 1</h2>

<h3>Which type of dog would you expect to find on a farm?</h3>

<form id="form">

  <lable>
    <img src="https://www.mybestfrienddogcare.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/border-collie-.png" width="150" height="150">
  </lable>
  <input type="radio" id="dog-one" name="dog">

  <label>
    <img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="150" height="150">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="dog-two" name="dog">

  <label>
    <img src="https://www.pdsa.org.uk/media/6615/german-shepherd-gallery-1-min.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&quality=100&height=500&bgcolor=fff&rnd=132019595560000000" width="150" height="150">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="dog-three" name="dog">

  <label>
    <img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2016/09/beagle-puppy-5-e1568913038666.jpg" width="150" height="150">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="dog-four" name="dog">

  <br /><br />
  <div id="results"></div>
  <br /><br />
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me this, I am now trying to copy the coding to get the same effects. This has been extremely helpful!

Comment: Hi Aryan, I am struggling to implement the JavaScript into my coding. I'm using Visual Studio Code. As mentioned I have only just started learning HTML and CSS, I understand that to use JavaScript I need to use jsconfig.json but some of the coding isn't registering. Would this perhaps be down to the program I'm using? or am I missing something more?

Comment: @Laufeena is this a plain HTML/CSS project with no frameworks?

Comment: I believe so. The end result is that I should be using my html link to an answers page to display the answers but also to display how many of the answers were correct too. I'm happy to learn JavaScript as Java is one of the coding languages I have a lot of interest in but I don't believe it has to be used in this task.

Comment: @Laufeena JavaScript actually has nothing to do with Java. JavaScript (aka JS) It was created to add front-end functionality to a website, which would not be possible with just HTML and CSS. To add JavaScript to an HTML file, you don't need a jsconfig.json file or any configuration files. Simply create the file in your root directory, name it `script.js`, and import it at the end of your HTML file just before the closing </body> tag with `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh. That's fantastic to know and thank you so much for the information. So i just need to create the script.js file and put all the JS in that file for it to work? obviously with the script code in my html file before the last body tag. I'll give this a go and get back to you if it's still not working properly. You really have been a massive help to me!

Comment: Aryan, I have finally gotten the JS working, is there any further steps I need to do in order for the correct answers to be added together for a total score to be displayed along with the correct and incorrect answers?

Comment: @Laufeena you can create a variable that increments by 1 each time they get a correct answer. You can also store the question number each time they get an answer correct and at the end display this information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group radio inputs with the same `name` in order to get the functionality you want, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<input type="radio" name="q1">

<input type="radio" name="q2">
<input type="radio" name="q2">
<input type="radio" name="q2">
```

Here, you'll only be able to select 1 option from q1 and 1 option from q2.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to use the radio function for all the questions, I'll implement this straight away.

Comment: I have managed to get the questions all set up properly with each question only having 1 answer to each, so thank you for that.

I am not trying to work out how to get the selected questions added up to display someone's overall score on the view answers page, is there a special type of code to do this?